# Errors passing no value to a string parameter with a default value

Tags: powershell

I am working from the command line. Let's say my example looks like this:

```
Param(
  [Parameter()] [string]$greeting="HelloWorld"
)
```

From the commandline I can do this: `mygreeting`
And it will output `HelloWorld`

Or I can do this: `mygreeting -greeting="whatever"`
And it will output `whatever`

Why can't I type this?:

```
mygreeting -greeting
```

without getting an error that the argument is missing?

In the code I want to be able to basically say:
If greeting is specified but has no value then set the value conditionally based on other things
If greeting is not specified use the default value

Comment: What do you mean by "no value"? Like if someone enters `mygreeting -greeting ""`? If you pass in a flag, I think it requires *something*

Answer (score 1):

**This is by design.** In PowerShell you are passing an argument by *specifying the name of the parameter followed with the value you want to pass* (except if its a switch or you using positional parameters where you only pass the value).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this  :

```
function test-test {
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param (
    [parameter(Position = 0)]
    [string]$greetings = "hi world"
    )

    $greetings
}
```

to set value about your parameter 
and u can call it like this :

```
test-test "something"
```

or

```
test-test -greetings "something"
```

but you cant run it like `parameter="value"`

if you want to use this you should use :

```
test-test ($greetings = "ssss")
```

like this.
but actually this `$greetings` not the same of variable in your function because have grater oscope than youre function.